# Multi-screen apps for the google tv platform with just the Google TV emulator

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, google-tv

I am trying to develop a [multi-screen app](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/) for the Google TV platform using the Google TV emulator. So far, I have been unsuccessful in getting the [Anymote](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/index) connection to work.

The problem lies in the fact that every android emulator lies behind its own virtual firewall/router and is not on the same network as an external device/emulator. The multicast discovery phase in the protocol fails in such a situation. I have tried to use ADB redirections and have also tried multiple configurations such as using the remote control app on a device and even on an emulator on the same machine as the GoogleTV emulator but nothing seems to work and it fails to create a connection socket.

My question is: Has anyone successfully made a multi-screen app for the Google TV platform by using the GoogleTV emulator? If so, then please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google TV emulator does not broadcast an Anymote endpoint via mDNS, so it presently cannot be used for developing multi-screen apps using Anymote.  If you can provide the Google TV team with some information about what you're developing, using the form at http://goo.gl/tVw4i, we may be able to help you find an alternative to using the emulator for development.

Feature request filed at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=15.  Pease star it if it's important to you!

Answer (score 0):

I could never get Anymote to work on the emulator. I did all of my development for my app, Able Remote, on the Google TV devices.

Answer (score 0):

You may edit [BroadcastDiscoveryClient](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/BroadcastDiscoveryClient.java) to use unicast instead of multicast to do the discovery or you can even avoid the discovery completely and force your emulator address.
Haven't tried it yet, but seems possible.

Comment: Forcing the emulator address doesn't work quite nicely either since it is on a different subnet and redirections just don't work when doing the authentication bit. Thanks for the tip though.